# how to validate Microsoft access token in c#

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs

I am using Microsoft external login in my application using JavaScript. I'm getting access token in client side and send to C# web API. I need to validate that access token in server side.

Please give me suggestions.
Thanks.

Comment: Are you using OWIN and Identity?

Comment: Yes, I am using owin